# APP_INITIALIZER not resolving promises before continuing to other providers

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, app-initializer

I'm struggling to see what I am missing here. Hopefully it's just a small issue.

My problem lies with the APP_INITIALIZER not completely resolving.

I have two services: AppSettingsService and SomethingService. I created a new injectable token "API_BASE_URL" that I want to inject in SomethingService. AppSettingsService has a method called setup() that sets the string "test" in a Promise. I want to finish resolving this promise before continuing on to set API_BASE_URL. However, it doesn't seem to want to wait!

I've attached a sandbox:

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/musing-tamas-ld7yqy?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwkub310006356hl54ij9c2%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwkub310002356hretmgoh0%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwkub310004356hbgq5vp63%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwkub310005356hnu6bedic%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqwkub310002356hretmgoh0%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwkub310002356hretmgoh0%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqwky8x900kg356hjv8lote5%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwkub300001356hfy45az32%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fapp%252Fapp.component.ts%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A9%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A9%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A14%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A14%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwky8x900kg356hjv8lote5%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522temporary%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clqwkub310005356hnu6bedic%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwkub310005356hnu6bedic%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqwl2dbx016s356hzuqddepz%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A4200%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwl2dbx016s356hzuqddepz%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clqwkub310004356hbgq5vp63%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwkub310003356hres5maxr%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqwkub310004356hbgq5vp63%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqwkub310003356hres5maxr%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Open the console and have a look. It runs as:

"Executing promise" (this is expected)
"Getting test string too early" (this I would expect after the promise has resolved)
"undefined" (this is because I am printing appSettings.test but it hasn't been set yet because the Promise hasn't completed)
"Resolving promise" (this happens shortly after (because of the setTimeout())

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't see `APP_INITIALIZER` being used

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev it's in the app.module.ts

Comment: Your demo is empty (its a starter)

Comment: My apologies, I haven't used the sandbox before. Hopefully that's fixed now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return statement is missing for all the providers `useFactory` sections, kindly find below the corrected code!

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppSettingsService } from './app-settings.service';
import { API_BASE_URL } from './something.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  providers: [
    AppSettingsService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      multi: true,
      deps: [AppSettingsService],
      useFactory: (appSettingsService: AppSettingsService) => {
        return () => {
          return appSettingsService.setup();
        };
      },
    },
    {
      provide: API_BASE_URL,
      deps: [AppSettingsService],
      useFactory: (appSettingsService: AppSettingsService) => {
        console.log('Getting test string too early');
        console.log(appSettingsService.test);
        return appSettingsService.test;
      },
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/lucid-joana-dn678s?file=%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts%3A1%2C1-36%2C1)

Comment: Well that was silly! Thank you :)